# Implementing renaming and deletion in java watchservice

Tags: java, file, directory, listener, watchservice

I tried to implement simple renaming in java WatchService.

My assumption is:    when files are renamed, three operations are performed

- Deletion of file xxx
- creation of file yyy
- modification of file yyy

Below are my codes:

**MyWatcher.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
    import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
    import java.nio.file.Path;
    import java.nio.file.Paths;
    import java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds;
    import java.nio.file.WatchEvent;
    import java.nio.file.WatchKey;
    import java.nio.file.WatchService;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class MyWatcher {

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        public static void main(String[] strings) {

            Path myWatchPath = Paths.get("D:\\log4j");
            long preventDuplicateTime = 0;
            FileDelete onDelete = new FileDelete();//this object must be thread safe
            List<String> notifications = new ArrayList<String>();

            WatchService myPathWatchService = null;
            try {
                myPathWatchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                myWatchPath.register(myPathWatchService,
                        StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE,
                        StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE,
                        StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            boolean isKeyValid = true;
            while (isKeyValid) {
                WatchKey myPathWatchKey = null;
                try {
                    myPathWatchKey = myPathWatchService.take();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();// throw
                }
                    for (WatchEvent watchEvent : myPathWatchKey.pollEvents()) {
                        //WatchEvent.Kind kind = watchEvent.kind();
                        if (StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE.equals(watchEvent
                                .kind())) {
                            String fileName = watchEvent.context().toString();
                            if(onDelete.status == -1)
                             System.out.println("File Created:" + fileName + " "
                                    + watchEvent.context());
                            else{
                                if(onDelete.status == 0){
                                    onDelete.createdTime = System.nanoTime();
                                if (onDelete.deletedTime / 10000000 == onDelete.createdTime / 10000000) {
                                    onDelete.createdFile = watchEvent.context().toString();
                                    onDelete.status++;
                                    notifications.add("File Created:" + fileName);
                                }else{
                                    for (String string : notifications) {
                                        System.out.println(string);
                                    }
                                    notifications = new ArrayList<String>();
                                    System.out.println("File Created:" + fileName + " "
                                            + watchEvent.context());
                                    onDelete = new FileDelete();  //Time duration not close (seems not renamed)
                                }
                                }else{
                                    //this should never come here!!
                                    onDelete = new FileDelete();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE.equals(watchEvent
                                .kind())) {
                            String fileName = watchEvent.context().toString();
                            if(onDelete.status == -1){
                                onDelete = new FileDelete();
                                onDelete.status++;
                                onDelete.deletedFile = watchEvent.context().toString();
                                onDelete.deletedTime = System.nanoTime();
                                notifications.add("File deleted:" + fileName);
                            }
                            //System.out.println("File deleted:" + fileName);   // push to notfication to array for later use
                        }
                        if (StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY.equals(watchEvent
                                .kind())) {
                            long current = System.nanoTime();
                            String fileName = watchEvent.context().toString();
                            if(!(preventDuplicateTime/10000000 == current/10000000))
                                notifications.add("File modified:" + fileName);
                            preventDuplicateTime = (System.nanoTime());
                            onDelete.modifiedFile= fileName;
                            onDelete.modifiedTime =System.nanoTime();
                            if(onDelete.status != 1){
                                for (String messages : notifications) {
                                    System.out.println(messages);
                                }
                            onDelete= new FileDelete();
                            notifications = new ArrayList<String>();
                            }
                            else if(onDelete.createdFile.equals(onDelete.modifiedFile))
                                    if( onDelete.createdTime /10000000 == onDelete.modifiedTime/10000000){
                                        System.out.println("File renamed:" + fileName);
                                        onDelete = new FileDelete();
                                        notifications = new ArrayList<String>();
                             }
                        }
                    /*}*/

                }
                isKeyValid = myPathWatchKey.reset();
            }
        }
    }
```

**FileRename.java**

```
public class FileRename {
    int status =-1;
    String deletedFile = "";
    long deletedTime = 0 ;
    String createdFile = "";
    long createdTime =0 ;
    String modifiedFile = "";
    long modifiedTime = 0 ;
}
```

It's showing perfectly on renaming operations but the problem is I can't figure how to show for onDelete. Because each delete is pushed into notifications!! Or else help me implement renaming!!

*NOTE please don't suggest third party jars! (Since most of them, like JNotify, are OS dependent)

Comment: For me this seems to be not possible, if you don't watch the files itself (maybe keeping the fileKey() and compare it within the catched events). From a directory point of view how you would make the difference between `delete file1 + create file2` and `delete file1 + create file1_with_new_name`? On Linux the inode could tell you if it's the same file. Regarding the javadoc fileKey() would use the inode for the identification.

Comment: @SubOptimal My aim is to watch a single directory...Sorry I didn't get you can you pls elaborate it

Comment: @SubOptimal seems inode is OS specific I want generic solution ,Is it possible  ?

Comment: Have a look to my edited answer. With plain Java runtime classes there is no way to achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please find below some explanation why an OS independent solution will not work. And why the event granularity of the Java `WatchService` is too weak for what you want to achieve.

Based on the available events (CREATE, MODIFY, DELETE) you cannot determine which action happened.

Take following example on a Linux machine

**create some test files**

```
touch /tmp/stackoverflow/foo /tmp/stackoverflow/foo2
```

**execute the following commands**

```
rm foo && cp foo2 bar && echo foo > bar
```

This will create following events (monitored with [WatchDir.java](https://github.com/jugsaar/jugsaar-meeting-9/blob/master/talks/java-nio2/src/main/java/de/jugsaar/meeting9/nio2/watchservice/WatchDir.java))

```
ENTRY_DELETE ..:..:.. [.........]: /tmp/stackoverflow/foo
ENTRY_CREATE 20:09:37 [rw.rw.rw.]: /tmp/stackoverflow/bar
ENTRY_MODIFY 20:09:37 [rw.rw.rw.]: /tmp/stackoverflow/bar
```

Following your assumption of the events order this would have been a `rename` action.

Wheras `mv bar foobar` creates following events.

```
ENTRY_DELETE ..:..:.. [.........]: /tmp/stackoverflow/bar
ENTRY_CREATE 19:55:37 [rw.rw.rw.]: /tmp/stackoverflow/foobar
```

Now the same for a Window machine

**create some test files**

```
rem.>c:/temp/stackoverflow/foo
rem.>c:/tmp/stackoverflow/foo2
```

**execute the following commands**

```
del foo
copy foo2 bar
```

This will create following events

```
ENTRY_DELETE ..:..:.. [.........]: c:\temp\stackoverflow\foo
ENTRY_CREATE 19:59:10 [.........]: c:\temp\stackoverflow\bar
ENTRY_MODIFY 19:59:10 [.........]: c:\temp\stackoverflow\bar
```

Following your assumption of the events order this would have been a `rename` action.

Wheras `ren bar foobar` creates in this case the same events order.

```
ENTRY_DELETE ..:..:.. [.........]: c:\temp\stackoverflow\bar
ENTRY_CREATE 20:02:41 [.........]: c:\temp\stackoverflow\foobar
ENTRY_MODIFY 20:02:41 [.........]: c:\temp\stackoverflow\foobar
```

Contrary with `iwatch /tmp/stackoverflow/` on a Linux machine you can determine exactly what happen.

Executing the commands `rm foo && cp foo2 bar && echo foo > bar`
produces following inotify events.

```
[31/Mär/2015 20:25:40] IN_DELETE /tmp/stackoverflow//foo
[31/Mär/2015 20:25:40] * /tmp/stackoverflow//foo is deleted
[31/Mär/2015 20:25:40] IN_CREATE /tmp/stackoverflow//bar
[31/Mär/2015 20:25:40] IN_CLOSE_WRITE /tmp/stackoverflow//bar
[31/Mär/2015 20:25:40] * /tmp/stackoverflow//bar is closed
[31/Mär/2015 20:25:40] IN_CLOSE_WRITE /tmp/stackoverflow//bar
[31/Mär/2015 20:25:40] * /tmp/stackoverflow//bar is closed
```

whereas `mv bar foobar` creates following inotify events

```
[31/Mär/2015 20:27:10] IN_MOVED_FROM /tmp/stackoverflow//bar
[31/Mär/2015 20:27:10] IN_MOVED_TO /tmp/stackoverflow//foobar
[31/Mär/2015 20:27:10] * /tmp/stackoverflow//bar is moved to /tmp/stackoverflow//foobar
```

**edit** The related Java source code to confirm my explanation. There is no way (in plain Java) to find out if one file is renamed or one file is deleted and another one is created (at the same time).

[WindowsWatchService.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/windows/classes/sun/nio/fs/WindowsWatchService.java) line 462

```
// Translate file change action into watch event
private WatchEvent.Kind<?> translateActionToEvent(int action)
{
    switch (action) {
        case FILE_ACTION_MODIFIED :
            return StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY;

        case FILE_ACTION_ADDED :
        case FILE_ACTION_RENAMED_NEW_NAME :
            return StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE;

        case FILE_ACTION_REMOVED :
        case FILE_ACTION_RENAMED_OLD_NAME :
            return StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE;

        default :
            return null;  // action not recognized
    }
}
```

[LinuxWatchService.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/solaris/classes/sun/nio/fs/LinuxWatchService.java) line 376

```
/**
 * map inotify event to WatchEvent.Kind
 */
private WatchEvent.Kind<?> maskToEventKind(int mask) {
    if ((mask & IN_MODIFY) > 0)
        return StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY;
    if ((mask & IN_ATTRIB) > 0)
        return StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY;
    if ((mask & IN_CREATE) > 0)
        return StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE;
    if ((mask & IN_MOVED_TO) > 0)
        return StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE;
    if ((mask & IN_DELETE) > 0)
        return StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE;
    if ((mask & IN_MOVED_FROM) > 0)
        return StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE;
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Any1 got a clue as to why they would simply reduce these informations and no pass em on so we had a better granularity?

Comment: @JayC667 I believe not every event is supported on every filesystem.