# Rename detection using file watch service

Tags: java, nio, watchservice

We are using java.nio file watch service.

Problem is with the rename detection. For rename , the watch service sends two events delete and create. We consider it as batch and if it is within a certain timespan we consider it as a rename event.

Is there any other way/logic which can be used to capture the rename event ?

Probably its a duplicate with another question, but there was no conclusive answers being given in that thread. And also technology changes a lot in 3-4 years. So was wondering if anyone has solved this problem.

Comment: ok..i understand it being duplicate :)...but there was no clonclusive answer in that thread and also technology change in 3-4 years...so was wondering if anyone has solved this problem using pure java sdk apis...

Comment: Well you could read [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29368257/implementing-renaming-and-deletion-in-java-watchservice) for a duplicate from this year, or [any of these](http://letmegooglethatforyou.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java+watchservice+rename), most of which will tell you the same as that duplicate: you can't have an cross-platform compatible solution. You might, therefore, need to supply more information to get a good answer.